# Add js library to custom ckeditor4 plugin

Tags: javascript, 9, wysiwyg

**How can an external JS library be integrated into Drupal for use within a custom Ckeditor4 plugin?**

My custom plugin needs to set a javascript cookie each time I click on the plugin icon and unset when I close the plugin dialog.

I attempted to use JQuery which didn't work and when I googled the issue, I found a post saying the [jquery-cookie is being replaced with js-cookie](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_page/issues/3268996).

I attempted to install js-cookie and tried the following example:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR, Cookies) {
    Cookies.set('foo', 'bar')
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR, window.Cookies);
```

but got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'set')

*I'm not sure if it's becuase of the way I attached the JS-Cookie library.*

**The following are the steps I took to attach the library.**

I used a composer [plugin](https://github.com/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender) to require [js-cookie](https://asset-packagist.org/package/npm-asset/js-cookie) into my custom module. My composer.json is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "my/module",
    "description": "Custom module ckeditor4 plugin",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "my-name",
            "email": "my@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": [
            "npm-asset",
            "bower-asset"
        ],
        "installer-paths": {
            "libraries/asset-packagist/{$name}": [
                "type:npm-asset",
                "type:bower-asset"
            ]
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
        "npm-asset/js-cookie": "^3.0",
        "npm-asset/cookie": "^0.5.0"
    }
}
```

Which downloads the required library into the following directory structure from the root of the module code base:

```
libraries
├── asset-packagist
│   ├── cookie
│   └── js-cookie
```

At this point I am able to create an entry in my_module.libraries.yml using the following:

```
js-cookie:
  js:
    libraries/asset-packagist/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.min.mjs: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

. . . and attach the library to a form using the following hook_form_alter implementation:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/js-cookie';
}
```

And I confirmed the js-cookie library is sucessfully loaded in the HTML:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete these lines from your library file.

```
js-cookie:
  js:
    libraries/asset-packagist/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.min.mjs: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

You try need to replace the used library **core/jquery.cookie** to **core/js-cookie**.

my_module.libraries.yml

```
my_library:
  js:
    js/my_library.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/js-cookie
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery
```

js/my_library.es6.js

```
(($, Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR, cookies) => {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: () => {
      // Set a cookie.
      cookies.set('cutest', 'red panda');
      // Retrieve a cookie.
      const cutest = cookies.get('cutest');
      // Remove a cookie.
      cookies.remove('cutest');
      // Store and retrieve as a JSON object. Use of the getJSON method should be avoided as that will be deprecated in js-cookie 3.0.0.
      cookies.set('cutest', JSON.stringify({ animal: 'red panda' }));
      const cutest = JSON.parse(cookies.get('cutest'));
    },
  };
})(jQuery,Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR,window.Cookies));
```

Here is the official documentation with an anchor to the part that explain how to use js-cookie: https://www.drupal.org/node/3104677